# Unable to convert pygame to executable with virtualenv and cx_Freeze

Tags: python, pygame, virtualenv, python-3.5, cx-freeze

I am unable to turn a game I made from a tutorial on youtube into an executable with cx_Freeze. I'm using virtualenv and cx_Freeze is version 5.0. When running the game I get a message:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00002c24 (most recent call first):
```

Below is the trace backs when creating the file.

```
(pygame) G:\Programming\scripts\Python\PyGame\compile_files>python setup.py build
running build
running build_exe
creating directory build\exe.win32-3.5
copying G:\Programming\scripts\Python\virtualenv\pygame\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\bases\Console.exe -> build\exe.win32-3.5\Slither.exe
copying G:\Programming\scripts\Python\virtualenv\pygame\Scripts\python35.dll -> build\exe.win32-3.5\python35.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 12, in <module>
    executables=executables
  File "G:\Programming\scripts\Python\virtualenv\pygame\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 349, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "G:\python\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "G:\python\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "G:\python\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "G:\python\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "G:\python\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "G:\python\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "G:\Programming\scripts\Python\virtualenv\pygame\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 219, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "G:\Programming\scripts\Python\virtualenv\pygame\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 623, in Freeze
    self._FreezeExecutable(executable)
  File "G:\Programming\scripts\Python\virtualenv\pygame\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 225, in _FreezeExecutable
    self._AddVersionResource(exe)
  File "G:\Programming\scripts\Python\virtualenv\pygame\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 165, in _AddVersionResource
    trademarks = exe.trademarks)
  File "G:\Programming\scripts\Python\virtualenv\pygame\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 759, in __init__
    parts = version.split(".")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

(pygame) G:\Programming\scripts\Python\PyGame\compile_files>`
```

My setup file is:

```
import cx_Freeze
import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "G:\\python\\Python35-32\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "G:\\python\\Python35-32\\tcl\\tk8.6"

executables=[cx_Freeze.Executable("Game.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="Game",
    options={"build_exe":{"packages":["pygame"],"include_files":["image1.png","image2.png"]}},
    description="Game",
    executables=executables
)
```

The images are in the same directory as the setup.py file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your setup file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable
setup(name="NAME OF YOUR PROGRAM",
         version="1.0",
         description="as above",
         executables=[Executable("NAME OF THE SCRIPT.py")])
```

After that, drag your png files to the folder into the same folder with your program.

```
python setup.py build
```

Finally put your png,jpg etc. files into that folder.

Comment: I added my current setup.py file which seems similar to what you have listed.

Comment: Any other ideas?